# Drawing hexagonal prisms

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, asymptote

Simmilar to:
[Drawing spheres](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422817/126078)

I want to draw multiple 3D hexagonal cylinders like this one:

[image]

with different sizes and positions.

Comment: This is called a hexagonal prism.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/draw-a-prism-in-tikz-or-pstricks

Answer (score 8):

Using Asymptote and the unofficial polyhedron_js asymptote package (available here https://github.com/pivaldi/asymptote-packages) you can define easily such a cylinder and play with it.
Please find the code (assuming that you have polyhedron_js.asy)

```
import polyhedron_js;

// comment the following line for OpenGl
//settings.render=0;

settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.outformat="pdf"; // for opacity

size(10cm);

currentprojection=perspective(7,6,4); //if you want perspectivic look
//currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,0.5); //if you want othographic look
currentlight=(1,1,2);
// currentlight=nolight;


polyhedron hexa_cyl;
guide hexa=polygon(6);
hexa_cyl[0]=(point(hexa,0).x,point(hexa,0).y,0);
for(int i=1;i<6;++i) hexa_cyl[0]=hexa_cyl[0]--(point(hexa,i).x,point(hexa,i).y,0);
hexa_cyl[0]=hexa_cyl[0]--cycle;
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
{
hexa_cyl[i+1]=point(hexa_cyl[0],i)--point(hexa_cyl[0],(i+1)%6)--
(shift(0,0,1)*point(hexa_cyl[0],(i+1)%6))--(shift(0,0,1)*point(hexa_cyl[0],i))--cycle;
}
hexa_cyl[6]=shift(0,0,1)*hexa_cyl[0];


polyhedron[] p1={scale(1,1,3)*hexa_cyl};
polyhedron[] p2={shift(4,1,1)*rotate(60,(2,1,3))*hexa_cyl};
polyhedron[] p3={shift(-2,-2,-2)*rotate(90,(1,0,0))*scale(.5,.5,2)*hexa_cyl};

filldraw(p1,new pen[]{0.8green},op=0.9);
filldraw(p2,new pen[]{0.8blue},op=0.9);
filldraw(p3,new pen[]{0.8yellow},op=0.9);
```

and the result
[image]

Comments : the `hexa_cyl` has height 1 (the `z` direction), the base is the regular hexagone constructed on the unit-circle, `(0,0,0)` is the center of the base. From the documentation

`scale(x,y,z)` : scales by x in the x direction, by y in the y direction, and by z in the z direction

`shift(triple v)` : translates by the triple v

`rotate(real angle, triple v)` : rotates by angle in degrees about an axis v through the origin;

so that a combination of the three routines performed on `hexa_cyl` gives the hexagonal prism that you want.

Comment: Oh wow! That's really stunning!

Comment: This seems more like what I'm looking for. I don't fully understand the code, what is positioning part? how rotation works?

Comment: @ErnestoIglesias: please see the added comments and the asymptote documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/hexagonal prism/.cd,
rotation angle/.initial=0,
height/.initial=4,
diameter/.initial=2
}
\tikzset{pics/.cd, 
hexi/.style={code={
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{mod(\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/rotation angle},60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phieff}{(\tdplotmainphi-mod(\tdplotmainphi+690,60)+30)}
\draw[fill=gray!60] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(0+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(0+\myangle+\phieff)},0) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},0) 
 --({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(0+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(0+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!20] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},0) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},0) 
 --({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!10] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},0) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-180+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-180+\myangle+\phieff)},0) 
 --({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-180+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-180+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --
 ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle+\phieff)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- cycle;
\ifdim\tdplotmaintheta pt<90pt
 \draw[fill=gray!15] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(0+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(0+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-180+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-180+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-240+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-240+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-300+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-300+\myangle)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/height}) --  cycle;
\else
 \draw[fill=gray!85] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(0+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(0+\myangle)},0) --
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-60+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-60+\myangle)},0) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-120+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-120+\myangle)},0) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-180+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-180+\myangle)},0) --
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-240+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-240+\myangle)},0) -- 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*cos(-300+\myangle)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/hexagonal prism/diameter}*sin(-300+\myangle)},0) --  cycle;
\fi
}}}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,font=\sffamily]
% \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-3,-1) rectangle (3,5);
 \pic {hexi};
 \pic[shift={(5,0,0)},/hexagonal prism/height=3] {hexi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]